# Retrieve min and max salary ranges from a string in SQL

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I have a table with column Salary Range

| Salary Range |
| --- |
| $43K-$84K (LinkedIn est.) |
| $125K-$170K (Yahoo est.) |
| $10K-$30K (Glassdoor est.) |

I would like to retrieve the min and max salary from the column salary range as shown below

| Salary Range | min | max |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $43K-$84K (Glassdoor est.) | 43 | 84 |
| $125K-$170K (Glassdoor est.) | 125 | 170 |
| $10K-$30K (Glassdoor est.) | 10 | 30 |

What is the best way to achieve this in SQL.

Comment: It seems you don't realise how different the dialect for each RDBMS is. You wouldn't tag a C# question with VB.Net because the languages are both by Microsoft and have *some* similarities; the same is true here. Just because they are all RDBMS doesn't mean that they are all relevant to your question about Big Query; they are not. if you really want a full explanation, then please ask about it on [meta].

Comment: You want to use REGEXP_EXTRACT function, but you'll have to construct a regex string twice- one for first occurrence and one for 2nd. Honestly I hate regex so much that I dont feel like submitting an answer ;). You might repost a new question tagged with regex because there are experts in regex that could answer that pretty quickly I bet.

Comment: I do not expect a tailor made sql query as a solution. I expect more of a headsup on how to go about the issue. Answer similar to what Josh provided. I am sure  'realising how different the dialect for each RDBMS'' is irrelevant here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the answer from bigquery -

```
with cte as
(
  select '$43K-$84K (LinkedIn est.)' as salary_range union all
select '$125K-$170K (Yahoo est.)' union all
select '$10K-$30K (Glassdoor est.)'
)select salary_range, 
regexp_extract(split(salary_range,'-')[ORDINAL(1)],r'[0-9]+') min_sal,
regexp_extract(split(salary_range,'-')[ORDINAL(2)],r'[0-9]+') max_sal 
from cte;
```

Result -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With one **regexp** invocation,

```sql
SELECT salary_range, sal[OFFSET(0)] min, sal[OFFSET(1)] max 
  FROM cte, UNNEST([STRUCT(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(salary_range, r'\$([0-9]+)K') AS sal)])
```